# Why can't the route be dragged when setting draggable = true?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I think this is a very simple problem. But I have not found the reason.

My code is like this:

```js
var request = {
  origin: new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLng),
  destination: new google.maps.LatLng(targetLat, targetLng),
  waypoints: stopovers,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
  provideRouteAlternatives: true
};



directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
      suppressMarkers: true,
      draggable: true
    }
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setOptions({
      polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: colors[i]
      }
    });

    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

  } else
    console.log("error " + status);
});
```

When the route is displayed on the map, I can find the "point" which is used to drag the route.

But if I really drag the route, the route will recover to its original status after I release the mouse button.

Did anyone have the similar problem?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [your code as posted works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/onptxyrh/1/)

Comment: I upvoted @geocodezip's comment since it should solve your problem and more relevant to your code than my answer..

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with the usage of : `waypoints: stopovers,` in your code please refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests. If we had a fiddle we'd work on that, but till then please take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2vh4o89/) that I created for you using and articles code taken from [this article](http://technico.qnownow.com/make-directions-draggable-using-google-maps-v3/) which seems to define the rendererOptions in a higher level:

```
var map;
var rendererOptions = {draggable: true};
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

$(document).ready(function () {
        //draw a map centered at Empire State Building Newyork
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.748492, -73.985496);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("divDirections"));

        $("#btnGetDirections").click(function(){
            calcRoute($("#txtAddress1").val(),$("#txtAddress2").val());
        });  

});

function calcRoute(start,end) {
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    provideRouteAlternatives : false
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Woorer, thanks! I need some time to study your code and provided links. But before that, I find this sentence in API document: "The DirectionsRenderer will dynamically update to show the modified path. Upon release, a transitional waypoint will be added to the map (indicated by a small white marker)". Actually, my route has reached waypoints' upper bound (8). So If I drag the path, another way point is needed. So my drag operation does not work. Is that the reason? I am going to test it

Comment: That doesn't explain it. How were we supposed to know how many waypoints you had? You didn't provide any information about your waypoints in your question. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [your code as posted works for me with 8 waypoints](http://jsfiddle.net/onptxyrh/3/)